# PHP Syntax error Firebase

Tags: php, android, html, firebase

I was following a tutorial for [push notification using firebase](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-push-notification-tutorial-using-firebase) and tried to upload all files to 000webhost.com, but I'm getting the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONST in /home/a6748590/public_html/FirebasePush/send.php on line 4

I've tried to search many topics here about php syntax error with no success fixing my issue.

Comment: and you have code, right?

Comment: *"Because class constants don't have a visibility in PHP. They are always static and callable from outside (i.e. public). Just remove the `private` before."*

Answer (score 0):

Replace this part:

```
const DEFAULT_URL = 'https://simplifiedcoding.firebaseio.com/';
```

with:

```
define('DEFAULT_URL', 'https://simplifiedcoding.firebaseio.com/');
```

in your *send.php* file (line 4)

Comment: now I'm getting                         Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home/a6748590/public_html/FirebasePush/send.php on line 32           Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/a6748590/public_html/FirebasePush/send.php on line 32

Comment: @kleisersarifo my fault, remove the white space in the end of the first define argument. I will fix my answer